# Installation error of 1c bitrix

Tags: php, html, битрикс, сокет, веб-сервер

Я действовал согласно видео на [Install PHP, Apache and MySQL](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5UMDy0EeUU). Одним из отличий является то, что у меня была несколько другая иерархия папок и файлов. Моя иерархия следующая: корень - C:\Apache24; вложенные папки и файлы - php, mysql-8.0, C:\Apache24\htdocs\bitrixsetup.php.

1. Я загрузил **Apache 2.4 binaries VC11** под свою систему по ссылке [Download Apache](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC11) . У меня 64 разрядная ОС, поэтому Вам понадобился файл с именем, наподобие **httpd-2.4.xx-win64-VC11.zip**
2. Разархивируем содержимое папки Apache24 из скаченного архива в **С:\Apache24\apache**. Обратите внимание, что в D:\Apache24 нужно положить не папку Apache24 из архива, а ее содержимое. Инсталлировать ничего не требуется.
3. В файле **C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf** изменяем значение **ServerRoot** на **"C:/Apache24/"** (строка 37-39) и значение **DocumentRoot** (и **Directory** , строки 251-252) на **"C:/Apache24/htdocs"** (строки 242 и 243). Так же следует убрать комментарий со строки 227 и изменить ее на: **ServerName localhost:80**
4. Затем я изменяю параметры хранения логов в том же файле (находим параметры и изменяем):

```
ErrorLog "C:/Apache24/log/apache-error.log"

CustomLog "C:/Apache24/log/apache-access.log" common
```

Устанавливаем сервис Apache (от имени Администратора). Открываем командную строку от имени Администратора и вставляем туда следующую строку:

**C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k install**

Далее я настраиваю php как указано на [DenisBondar](http://blog.denisbondar.com/post/apache24php56win7). Файл **C:\Windows\System32\Users\drivers\etc\hosts** имеет вид

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com

127.0.0.1 lm.licenses.adobe.com127.0.0.1                   activate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1                   practivate.adobe.com
127.0.0.1                   na1r.services.adobe.com
127.0.0.1                   hlrcv.stage.adobe.com
127.0.0.1   shop.local
127.0.0.1   test
127.0.0.1   test.ru
127.0.0.1   www.test.ru
127.0.0.1   secondtest
127.0.0.1   secondtest.ru
127.0.0.1   www.secondtest.ru
127.0.0.1   1c-bitrix
127.0.0.1   1c-bitrix.ru
127.0.0.1   www.1c-bitrix.ru
127.0.0.1   www.1c-bitrix.ru:80
127.0.0.1   www.1c-bitrix.ru:443
127.0.0.1   ssl://www.1c-bitrix.ru
127.0.0.1   ssl://www.1c-bitrix.ru:443
127.0.0.1   ssl://www.1c-bitrix.ru:80
```

Затем я устанавливаю MySQL [Blog](http://blog.denisbondar.com/post/apache24php56win7) как указано на том же сайте. 
    Файл **C:\Apache24\mysql-8.0\my.ini** имеет вид

```
[client]

port=3306


[mysqld]

port=3306

basedir="C:\\Apache24\\data"
datadir="C:\\Apache24\\data\\db"
#character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=TRUE
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size=16M
max_allowed_packet= 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Затем я открываю страницу http:/localhost/bitrixsetup.php и вижу страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаю ошибку

```
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://www.1c-bitrix.ru:443 (��������� �� �����������, �.�. ������ ������� ������ ������ �� ���������. ) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\bitrixsetup.php on line 788
```

Часть файла **C:/Apache24/htdocs/bitrixsetup.php** (взят с https://www.1c-bitrix.by/download/cms.php ) приведена ниже

```
    // КОНЕЦ: ИНИЦИАЛИЗИРУЕМ, ЕСЛИ ПРОДОЛЖАЕМ СКАЧИВАТЬ

    //  SetCurrentStatus(LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_QUERY_SERVER"));

    // ИЩЕМ ФАЙЛ И ЗАПРАШИВАЕМ ИНФОРМАЦИЮ
    do
    {
        //      SetCurrentStatus(str_replace("#DISTR#", $strRealUrl, LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_QUERY_DISTR")));

        $lasturl = $strRealUrl;
        $redirection = "";

        $parsedurl = parse_url($strRealUrl);
        $useproxy = (($proxyAddr != "") && ($proxyPort != ""));

        if (!$useproxy)
        {
            $host = $parsedurl["host"];
            $port = $parsedurl["port"];
            $hostname = $host;
        }
        else
        {
            $host = $proxyAddr;
            $port = $proxyPort;
            $hostname = $parsedurl["host"];
        }

$port = $port ? $port : ($ssl ? 443 : 80);

//      SetCurrentStatus(str_replace("#HOST#", $host, LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_CONN2HOST")));
$sockethandle = fsockopen(($ssl ? 'ssl://' : '').$host, $port, $error_id, $error_msg, 30);
//debug_backtrace();
print_r(error_get_last());
//print_r(debug_backtrace());
//$err=iconv(iconv_get_encoding(, "UTF-8", $error_msg);
//echo mb_detect_encoding($error_msg);
//echo error_reporting(E_WARNING);
//echo(mb_detect_encoding(error_reporting(E_WARNING)));

//echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($error_msg), mb_detect_encoding(error_reporting(E_WARNING)), $error_msg);
//$errr=substr(error_get_last()['message'], 0, strlen(error_get_last()['message']) - strlen($error_msg) - 2 - strlen(' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\bitrixsetup.php on line 788'));
$e1=substr(error_get_last()['message'], 0, 60);
echo '<br>';
echo $e1;
echo mb_detect_encoding($e1);
echo '</br>';
echo '<br>';
echo $error_msg;
echo mb_detect_encoding($error_msg);
echo '</br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Кодировка предупреждений - ';
echo mb_detect_encoding(error_reporting(E_WARNING));
echo '</br>';
//echo mb_detect_encoding($error_msg);
echo '<br>';
echo 'Кодировка последней ошибки - ';
echo mb_detect_encoding(error_get_last()['message']);
echo '</br>';
echo '<br>';
echo 'Кодировка последней ошибки - ';
//echo error_reporting(E_WARNING).<br />;
echo mb_detect_encoding($error_msg);
echo '</br>';
echo mb_convert_encoding($error_msg, 'KOI8-R', 'utf-8');
echo iconv('utf-8', 'ascii', $error_msg);
//echo htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities($error_msg, ENT_COMPAT, 'ASCII', false)));
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_encode(htmlentities($error_msg, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false)));
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($error_msg, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false));
//echo error_reporting(E_WARNING)[1];
if (!$sockethandle)
{
    //          SetCurrentStatus(str_replace("#HOST#", $host, LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_NO_CONN2HOST"))." [".$error_id."] ".$error_msg);
    return false;
}
else
{
    if (!$parsedurl["path"])
        $parsedurl["path"] = "/";

    //          SetCurrentStatus(LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_QUERY_FILE"));
    $request = "";
    if (!$useproxy)
    {
        $request .= "HEAD ".$parsedurl["path"].($parsedurl["query"] ? '?'.$parsedurl["query"] : '')." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $request .= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $request .= "HEAD ".$strRealUrl." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $request .= "Host: $hostname\r\n";
        if ($proxyUserName)
            $request .= "Proxy-Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($proxyUserName.":".$proxyPassword)."\r\n";
    }

    if ($strUserAgent != "")
        $request .= "User-Agent: $strUserAgent\r\n";

    $request .= "\r\n";

    fwrite($sockethandle, $request);

    $result = "";
    //          SetCurrentStatus(LoaderGetMessage("LOADER_LOAD_WAIT"));

    $replyheader = "";
```

Comment: А зачем такие сложности как ручная установка компонентов сервера?

Comment: Ошибка говорит о том, что ваш сервер не может подключиться к серверу 1c-bitrix.ru смотрите настройки фаерволов и т.д. и разбирайтесь почему не прошло соединение.